# Error Acl/Laravel in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1, acl, role

I am having trouble creating user roles and permissions in my system.

I'm using Package acl / laravel, and documentation describes the stages. I wrote the following code UserController before the Get User Roles:

Documentation: https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl/wiki/Create-Roles

```
$users = User::all();
$users->getRoles();
return view('users.index', compact ('users'));
```

Error:

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
>   Method getRoles does not exist.

What is going wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getRoles` method exists for `User` object and when you use `User:all()` in `$users` variable you will get all users and not the single one.

So you can do:

```
$users = User::all();
return view('users.index', compact ('users'));
```

and in your Blade template you can in `foreach` loop user `getRoles()` method for single user and display them

Comment: Hello my friend, I did what you said, but I encountered this error : 
FatalErrorException in f3d2c905c9ca26d6bcc8f7cd30a0568b line 31:

Call to undefined function getRoles()

Comment: @Please include your Blade template in question